# Enable Huggingface LLM langchain streaming response in Flask API

Tags: python, flask, huggingface-transformers, langchain

I'm creating a flask API capable of streaming LLM (wrapped in langchain pipeline) response. I've been able to do this using the openai llm, but it does not seem to work for huggingface models.

Any help regarding the same would be appreciated!

Code snippet for model.py:

```
def load_llama2_13b():
    model_str = "meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-chat-hf"
    access_token = "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"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_str, use_auth_token=access_token)

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_str,
        device_map="auto",
        # quantization_config=bnb_config,
        trust_remote_code=True,
        use_auth_token=access_token)

    streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer)
    llm_pipeline = pipeline(
        "text-generation",  # task
        model=model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        trust_remote_code=True,
        device_map="auto",
        do_sample=True,
        max_new_tokens=300,
        streamer=streamer,
        eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
        model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.01, "repetition_penalty": 2.5}
    )

    llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=llm_pipeline)
    return llm

def query_llm(llm, query, task, prompt_template=None, vectordb=None):
    valid_tasks = ["instructive", "answer"]

    if task not in valid_tasks:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid task '{task}'. Allowed values are {valid_tasks}")

    if task == "instructive":
        template = """
                    You are an intelligent chatbot. Answer the question posed by user.
                    Question: {question}
                    Answer:"""


    if task == "answer":
        if prompt_template:
            template = prompt_template
        else:
            template = """
                    You are an intelligent chatbot. Given the context below, answer the question given at the end:
                    Context: {context}
                    QUESTION: {question} 
                    Answer:"""

        PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["context", "question"])
        llm_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm,
                                                chain_type="stuff",
                                                retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(),
                                                return_source_documents=True, chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": PROMPT})
        res = llm_chain({'query': query})
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        source_docs = [t.__dict__ for t in res["source_documents"]]

        return {"result": res["result"], "source_documents": source_docs}

    PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["question"])

    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=PROMPT, verbose=True)
    return {"result": llm_chain.run(question=query)}
```

and this is how it is getting consumed in api.py:

```
@app.route('/llmgeneration_stream', methods=['POST'])
def llm_generation_stream():
    json_data = {"status": 0, "message": "Failed"}
    start = time.time()

    data = json.loads(flask.request.data)

    model = data.get("model", "falcon-7b")
    query = data.get("query")
    task = data.get("task", "instructive")
    prompt_template = data.get("prompt_template", None)

    valid_models = ["falcon-7b", "openai", "falcon-40b", "llama2-13b", "llama2-7b", "llama2-70b"]
    if model not in valid_models:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid model '{model}'. Allowed values are {valid_models}")

    try:
        if model == "falcon-7b":
            llm = falcon_7b_llm
       

        return Response(stream_with_context(query_llm(llm, query, task, prompt_template, vectordb=vectordb)), mimetype='application/json')

        json_data["data"] = result
        json_data["message"] = "Passed"
        json_data["status"] = 1
        end = time.time()
        logger.info("llm API: " + "Time: " + str(end - start) + "Model: " + model + "Query" + query + "text_generated"
                    + str(result))

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, model, query)
    return flask.jsonify(json_data)
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippet, how you are loading models?

Comment: No, this snippet is about using your model, you are passing your llm (model) from another function

Comment: put that as well

Comment: As documentation says, you should have something like this in your code: `llm = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id=repo_id, model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.5, "max_length": 64}
)
llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)`
Where is this line in your code? You said that you cannot use hf models, i want to test your code but i need to understand process of model loading, i.e. class you are using, is it loaded on startu, etc.
Problem with openai api is that it actually a simple http api, while hf.co downloads models to your machine and it works in a different way.

Comment: added that code as well

Comment: are you getting any errors? if so add an error trace log.

Comment: @simpleApp this code doesnt give error, this gives response at one go. I need help with implementing streaming response here

Comment: Documentation says:
Currently, we support streaming for a broad range of LLM implementations, including but not limited to OpenAI, ChatOpenAI, ChatAnthropic, Hugging Face Text Generation Inference, and Replicate.

That means, directly loading model into memory and executing it in application itself is not supported. You need to setup [Text Generation Inference](https://github.com/huggingface/text-generation-inference) and than load your model in that side.